# equivalence to printf ("%.4d",x) in c++

Tags: c++, cout

I have an array like this:

```
int ar[] = {5, 11, 5923, 781};
```

I need to print numbers from `ar` array in XXXX way. I had:

`for(i = 1; i<=3; i++) printf ("%.4d", Pii[i]);`

and it works (prints `0005001159230781`). What is equivalence to `printf ("%.4d", Pii[i]);` when I want to use `cout`?

I tried:

```
cout.width( 4 );
cout.fill( '0' );
for(i = 0; i<=3; i++) cout << ar[i];
```

but it seems to work only for first argument (prints `0003115923781`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `std::setfill` and `std::setw` modifiers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    int ar[] = {5, 11, 5923, 781};
    for (auto ele : ar) {
        cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << ele << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But setting fill and width each time is as fast as printf is?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz all it does is call a function on the `ostream` in this case `cout`, it shouldn't be any slower than manually parsing the string modifier in `printf`

Comment: Yes, I checked it now. It is not slower. Thank you!